# iOS In App purchase status 21002, java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When verifying Apple IOS in-app purchase receipt with Apple server, a number of our transaction return as:

```
{"status":21002,"exception":"java.lang.NumberFormatException"}
```

May I know what's the cause of the problem? 
We have follow the Apple In-App purchase guide, i.e we will encode app store return receipt with Base 64 from iOS Client, prior sending the receipt for verification purpose

Note: Most of our transaction did go through, there is about 10% of the transactions with the above error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of possible causes:

- Somebody trying to hack your IAP receipt verification.  There are some techniques that insert bogus receipts in the hope the developer doesn't properly verify them.  The urus hack has this behaviour.
- Errors during testing lead to test receipts going to the production verifier.

I've seen these errors fairly often but I just don't recall which of these two causes this exact message.  I think they both do.  I have yet to have a customer complaint after seeing them.

If your volume is low enough (unfortunately, mine is), go into iTunes Connect and see if there are any sales that match the errors.  You can also take a look at the receipt data to see if it looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

there is one another posibility, you send only pucharse_info instead of whole decrypted JSON (with singature etc.)

```
var receipt = Ti.Utils.base64encode(evt.receipt).text;
```

Answer (score -1):

when you verify the receipt，maybe you can try the following code：

```
    NSData *receipt; // Sent to the server by the device

// Create the JSON object that describes the request
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
    @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
};
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];

if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */ }

// Create a POST request with the receipt data.
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
[storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

// Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (connectionError) {
        /* ... Handle error ... */
    } else {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        if (!jsonResponse) { /* ... Handle error ...*/ }
        /* ... Send a response back to the device ... */
    }
}];
```

Reference：https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Comment: You should never (unless if you don't care about MITM attack) validate the receipt directly from your device to Apple's endpoint. You should send it to your server, and from your server, you validate it with Apple's backend.